# Getting %'s of the most used row values

Tags: php, mysql

I track visitors country in my website and using this mysql query to get top visitor country names.

```
mysql_query("SELECT id,country, count(*) as num FROM track GROUP BY country ORDER BY count(*) desc limit 5")
```

It works perfectly. However, I want to get %s of the countries. How can I do that ?

Comment: you mean %s = percentage ?

Comment: Yes. I mean the percentages of the most used countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This join will report percentages:

```
select id, country, num, num*100/total pct
from (SELECT id,country, count(*) as num
      FROM track GROUP BY country
      ORDER BY num desc limit 5) x
join (select count(*) total from track) y
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I post the percentages ?

Comment: where these percentages stored ? I mean can I get these when I fetch data from mysql ? 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ ... };

Comment: It will be in `$row['pct']`. Don't you see the alias I assigned in the query?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the percentage? You can perform some basic numerical operations within MySQL - 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-functions.html

You can add another statement that calls the COUNT() of all the rows and then use the division operator to get the percentage, if you are looking to do it in the same query. You can also separate both as different queries.